# Query syntax for MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am stuck on the query synatax for the following scenario.

Lets say I have a table structured like:

id - name - count

Now I would like to get records whose count values sum to a particular number.

Example.

1 - A - 3
2 - A - 2
3 - A - 5
4 - B - 1
5 - C - 2

And I would like to get only records (tuples) whose count value added together gives me number 10.

The result should give me:

1 - A - 3
2 - A - 2
3 - A - 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this with a nested query, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(`count`) AS `sum`
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY `name`
)
WHERE `sum` = '10'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from tableName t
where 10 = (
    select sum(count)
    from tableName
    where name = t.name
)
```